# Deploy pre-compiled Razor view and remove Views folder?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've set **MvcBuildViews** to **true** and that precompiled the views into a DLL file. My question is: Can I deploy this DLL and just remove the Views folder entirely? Are there settings that I'll need to make?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) `MvcBuildViews` just compiles your views, but you still need to distribute them.

The RazorGenerator project would be of interest to you, and can behave exactly like you require.

http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/

Here's a write-up of how it works. I've used this before to build 'pluggable' MVC apps where only the binary is distributed, and not the views.

http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/precompile-your-mvc-views-using.html

Comment: it's weird because i also use the RazorGenerator, but it still deploys empty Views folders. Maybe it's a configuration thing.

Comment: Do you mean like if you use the Publish option or do a web deploy?

Comment: both. Maybe i need to set *build action* to `none` on all the Views folders, like i did on the view files.

Comment: Maybe, I'm not sure. Even if the folders are deployed, you should be able to safely delete them if you've configured RazorGenerator correctly.

Comment: that's what really annoys me. I had to go through about 100 views/templates and do that manually. Sucked. Wonder if someone has a T4 template or PSH script to do that...

Comment: Doesn't help you much now, but there is a nuget command you can run:  http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/discussions/285340

Comment: bummer! I have VS 2010 Express and can't install Razor Generator extension :) Thanks all.